# Xml parsing error trying to open Word

Tags: xml, ms-word, docx

just finished my work, saved and opened (for a control) docx - MS Word file and it can't open due to problem with the content. It says "Xml parsing error" and its location (line 2, column 2435). How can I fix this or at least get the text from xml format? Thank You very much.

Comment: Can you please show the invalid line?

Comment: To get the contents of the file you can't open anymore you can try to rename the extension to .xml or .txt instead or .docx. You will loose the formatting however, and you will not get rid of the erroneous line that causes the xml parsing error. Try to post the line to get further help if you were able to access the contents of your file.

Comment: @Yelnya That will not work with docx - a ZIP package of XML files.

Comment: Ahm yes - that means, the "Open With..." Command will not work either. What you can do, however, is use one of the free online "Convert Word to Text" Editors - just type that into Google Search. But only if your data is NOT sensible.

Comment: conwert word to text didn't help either..

Comment: @SebastianHofmann I did share the line, can you see it?

Comment: Yeah, I see, but could you add it to the question please and highlight column 2435?

Comment: `txbxContent` is not closed. This renders the XML invalid.

Comment: txbx><w:txbxContent></w:sdtContent></w:sdt><
it is the backlash - 22th character of this above.. sorry, not really used to StackOverflow

Comment: @SebastianHofmann don't think that is the problem, you can see more from the pic.

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian is right, you have some xml tag issues in the document you provided, maybe due to copy/paste errors.

My steps of action:

- unzipped Word file
- edited document.xml with an XML editor
- removed xml structure errors

(basically what is described here:
[How to Explore the Contents of a .docx File](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1dd8a59db46a63c694d79a69405b2d3b20180520002723/8876c4)
)

Download Link to restored .docx document:

[document_restored](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1dd8a59db46a63c694d79a69405b2d3b20180520002723/8876c4)

(File download is valid for 7 days)

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried to replace this content with the wrong one in xml file, still the docx file doesn't work.. Can you implement it so that docx file can open?

Comment: yes I managed to rearrange the document.xml so that your .docx can be reopened again. There were some erroneous tags in the xml and I believe a broken image was the final problem. I believe this image plus anchor was the reason why you were not able to solve the problem yourself by following mentioned steps in my proposed solution. I updated the file link now - you can find the fully restored .docx (apart from a logo or so) ready for download. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your current XML is invalid.

An example of valid XML:

```
<Elem1>
    <Elem2>
        <Elem3/>
    </Elem2>
</Elem1>
```

Your XML looks like this:

```
<Elem1>
    <Elem3>
        <Elem2>
    </Elem3>
    </Elem2>
</Elem1>
```

The problem with your XML is following:
you are opening `txbxContent` immediately before closing `sdtContent`, which is invalid markup. Furthermore, `txbxContent` is closed much later than `sdtContent`.
You could try to resolve the errors by removing the `txbxContent` and `txbx` tags or by closing them properly.

Comment: Here I am sending the docx file in case you do have time. Tried to follow your steps, still doesn't work
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqvt3p8wtp9af26/Marketing-Klement-2.docx?dl=0